# Setup Controllers Created with Render in Each Helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember template, I render an arbitrarily-sized array of `displayItem`s like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="display">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="display-items">
        {{#each displayItem in displayItems itemController="chart"}}
            {{render "chart" displayItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

However, I need to initialize some properties on the `chart` controller before the `chart` view renders. I know that for predefined view and controller structures, you can use the `setupController` hook on a `route`, but since these controllers are created dynamically, I thought I could use the `chart` controller's init property like so:

```
...other controller code
init: function() {
    var self = this;

    self._super();

    self.get("views")
    .then(function(views) {
        self.set("currentView", views.objectAt(0));
    });
}
...
```

But although the `init` hook is called, it is called too late--the view has already rendered with undefined values. Is there a way to setup dynamically-created controllers before their views render?

Comment: first off, I think you don't need to specify itemController="chart" in your loop, because render 'chart' displayItem will create a new chart controller for each element. And for your question, isn't render creating a new controller ?, In the docs have this: When no model is provided it gets the singleton instance of the corresponding controller. And When a model is provided it gets a unique instance of the corresponding controller. I guess it is creating a new controller, I haven't look at the source, but if it is creating a new controller, then, the init should be fired.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Init is firing, it's just firing after I want it to--it doesn't fire before the views are rendered, which means that properties required for the view to render start off as undefined...

Comment: I see, then, why don't you use and 'if' in your view ? an in your 'chart' controller create a property that will be 'true' only when all the properties you need are complete.. that way in the view, the code will be fired after the property is 'true'.

Comment: this is an example http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/1186/

Comment: great idea! I implemented it, and it works. If you want the bounty, go ahead and submit an answer explaining what you mean in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a property in your 'chart' controller, that will be observing all properties you need to be filled int before displaying the view. First off, I would recommend you to change this:

```
{{#each displayItem in displayItems itemController="chart"}}
  {{render "chart" displayItem}}
{{/each}}
```

to this:

```
{{#each displayItem in displayItems}}
  {{render "chart" displayItem}}
{{/each}}
```

'render' will instantiate a new charController for you, and its corresponding view. Then, in your 'chartController', add a property listening to all properties you need before rendering the view:

```
App.ChartController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isAllInformationComplete: function() {
    return !Ember.isEmpty('property1') && !Ember.isEmpty('property2');
  }.property('property1', 'property2')
});
```

and in your view, wrap your code in an if statement:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="chart">
  {{#if isAllInformationComplete}}
    All your view html, handlebars, etc...
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/1186/) for more details.

Comment: thank you so much! This is an awesome technique. I tried to give you the bounty, but I have to wait for 20 more hours--I'll give it to you then.